# Fitting with funtional parameter constraints in Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, non-linear-regression

I have some data `{x_i,y_i}` and I want to fit a model function `y=f(x,a,b,c)` to find the best fitting values of the parameters `(a,b,c)`; however, the three of them are not totally independent but constraints to `1<b` , `0<=c<1` and `g(a,b,c)>0`, where `g` is a "good" function. How could I implement this in Python since with curve_fit one cannot put the parametric constraints directly?

I have been reading with lmfit but I only see numerical constraints like `1<b, 0<=c<1` and not the one with `g(a,b,c)>0`, which is the most important.

Comment: The scipy docs for curve_fit() at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html has discussion and example of the bounds parameter.

Comment: @JamesPhillips curve_fit doesn't allow constraints like g(a,b,c)>0; they have to be only like {a0<a<a1, b0<b<b1, c0<c<c1}.

Comment: It may be possible to handle the `g(a, b, c) > 0` constraint with the expression-based constraint mechanism in `lmfit`, depending on what the function `g()` does.   You'll have to provide a more concrete example.

Comment: Well what does `f(x,a,b,c)` look like in the neighborhood  of `1<b , 0<=c<1`? How non-linear is it? Tell us a linearized approximation. You might have to piecewise model your region and constraint.

Comment: f(x,a,b,c) contains Gamma and Hypergeometric functions, so it is not easy to linearize...

Comment: By itself, containing complex mathematical functions is not necessarily impossible for constraints in `lmfit`.   One way to make a constraint would be to ask "can I write `a`, `b`, or `c` as an expression of the others?".  If so (even if that expression contains `\Gamma` functions, it *should* be possible to apply such a constraint.  Again, an example that is more concrete than "it uses gamma and hypergeometric functions" would be needed to give a more concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have

```
def g(a,b,c):
    c1 = (1.0 - c)
    cx = 1/c1
    c2 = 2*c1
    g  = a*a*b*gamma(2+cx)*gamma(cx)/gamma(1+3/c2)-b*b/(1+b**c2)**(1/c2)
    return g
```

If so, and if get the math right, this could be represented as

```
    a = sqrt((g+b*b/(1+b**c2)**(1/c2))*gamma(1+3/c2)/(b*gamma(2+cx)*gamma(cx)))
```

Which is to say that you *could* think about your problem as having a *variable* `g` which is > 0 and a value for `a` derived from `b`, `c`, and `g` by the above expression.

And that you *can* do with `lmfit` and its expression-based constraint mechanism.  You would have to add the `gamma` function, as with

```
  from lmfit import Parameters
  from scipy.special import gamma

  params = Parameters()
  params._asteval.symtable['gamma'] = gamma
```

and then set up the parameters with bounds and constraints.  I would probably follow the math above to allow better debugging and use something like:

```
  params.add('b', 1.5, min=1)
  params.add('c', 0.4, min=0, max=1)
  params.add('g', 0.2, min=0)
  params.add('c1', expr='1-c')
  params.add('cx', expr='1.0/c1')
  params.add('c2', expr='2*c1')
  params.add('gprod', expr='b*gamma(2+cx)*gamma(cx)/gamma(1+3/c2)')
  params.add('bfact', expr='(1+b**c2)**(1/c2)')
  params.add('a', expr='sqrt(g+b*b/(bfact*gprod))')
```

Note that this gives 3 actual variables (now `g`, `b`, and `c`) with plenty of derived values calculated from these, including `a`.  I would certainly check all that math.  It looks like you're safe from `negative**fractional_power`, `sqrt(negitive)`, and `gamma(-1)`, but be aware of these possibilities that will kill the fit.

You could embed all of that into your fitting function, but using constraint expressions gives you the ability to constrain parameter values independently of how the fitting or model function is defined.

Hope that helps.  Again, if this does not get to what you are trying to do, post more details about the constraint you are trying to impose.

Answer (score -1):

Like James Phillips, I was going to suggest SciPy's `curve_fit`.  But the way that you have defined your function, one of the constraints is on the function itself, and SciPy's bounds are defined only in terms of input variables.

What, exactly, are the forms of your functions?  Can you transform them so that you can use a standard definition of bounds, and then reverse the transformation to give a function in the original form that you wanted?

I have encountered a related problem when trying to fit exponential regressions using SciPy's `curve_fit`.  The parameter search algorithms vary in a linear fashion, and it's really easy to fail to establish a gradient.  If I write a function which fits the logarithm of the function I want, it's much easier to make curve_fit work.  Then, for my final work, I take the exponent of my fitted function.

This same strategy could work for you.  Predict **ln(y)**.  The value of that function can be unbounded.  Then for your final result, output **exp(ln(y)) = y**.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but if there was a method to reduce to inequalities the constraints, then I wouldn't post any question here ;-). The shape of the function g for example, involves Gamma functions, something like g(a,b,c)=a²b $\Gamma[2+1/(1-c)]\Gamma[1/(1-c)]/\Gamma[1+3/(2(1-c))]-b²/(1+b^(2(1-c)))^(1/2(1-c))$.... so there's no way to set numerical ranges separately. That's why I am asking this... In Wolfram Mathematica it is easy to express this constraint in functional way, however, I m trying to do it in Python...